# Overriding custom page variable

Tags: theming, 6

I created a template file (page-classifieds.tpl.php) for a classified page.  I would like to override variables of this particular page preferably using a preprocess function.

How can I do that?

`hook_preprocess_page()` overrides variables for all the pages. I don't want that to happen.

Comment: just check for `classifieds` type with `if else` statement :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/**
 * Variable preprocessor for the page template.
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'classified') {
    // Do things here.
    $variables['my_new_variable'] = 'Something';
  }
}
```

Note that the template page-classified.tpl.php will also match all sub paths of that page too, like:
yoursite.com/classified/something
yoursite.com/classified/something/something